# Unit-Test Generator

Tags: automation, unit-tests, code-generation

I have been requested to write a huge amount of tests on a C# project in .net 4.7.2. Doing in manually is taking me too much time and I find it really repetitive and monotonic.
I am wandering if there is a tool that can do it for me.

I used U.t boilerplate plugin to generate stubs But something more powerful can make my life much easier

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the code base written, most likely it won't be testable, you'll have to refactor and that may cause porblems\errors so I recommend using other tools to test your code and validate its stability.
I use Typemock’s ‘Suggest’ tool, it scans your code and generates tests for you, after they are generated you can either save them manually or click save as a C# class.
It can be triggered on a method or a whole class, and the most efficient feature of that is ‘work while idle’, I usually set it on and leave the computer to work whole night, that way it generates tests for the whole project and covers the most special scenarios.